# Java Download massive file giving Connection Shutdown/Reset on internet url after sometime

Tags: java, swing, httpurlconnection

I am building a swing application to download multiple files over the internet and save to a windows fileshare. I have used SwingWroker which internally uses the ExecutorService which internally queues them and downloads 10 at a time, but for some reason after downloading say 2 - 3 MB of file it stops and moves to next downloading file, They are downloaded in a batch of 10 as SwingWorker has fixed it in number of Threads for the Executor Service.

I have to write these files in a windows file share and I am using nio.FileChannels to do that. There are files ranging from 50-60 each weighing around 300MB - 500MB. The file links are located on a webpage to where I get to by login in using credentials on a login page(with a post request) over the internet before that I specify `CookieHandler.setDefault(new CookieManager())` at the beginning and so it behaves like a browser to me.

Another observation is when I download them locally (not to a windows server share) they do work fine.

This is the code I am using

```
import java.io.File;
import java.io.FileOutputStream;
import java.net.URL;
import java.net.URLConnection;
import java.nio.channels.Channels;
import java.nio.channels.FileChannel;
import java.nio.channels.ReadableByteChannel;

import javax.swing.SwingWorker;

public class DownloadProcess extends SwingWorker<Boolean, String> {

  private String urlPath, filePath;
  public DownloadProcess(String urlPath, String filePath){
    this.urlPath = urlPath;
    this.filePath = filePath;
  }             
  @Override
  protected Boolean doInBackground() {
    boolean taskState = true;
    URLConnection httpConn = null;
    ReadableByteChannel readableByteChannel = null;
    FileOutputStream fileOutputStream = null;
    FileChannel fileOutputChannel = null;
    try{
      //String filePath = "\\\\fileshare.server\\xyz.txt";
      //String urlPath = "http://example.com/anyBigFile.1GB.docx";
      File localFile = new File(filePath);//File share
      boolean itsThere = localFile!=null && localFile.exists();
      long done = itsThere ? localFile.length() : 0;
      URL url = new URL(urlPath);
      httpConn = url.openConnection();
      httpConn.setRequestProperty("Connection", "keep-alive");
      if(itsThere) {
        httpConn.setRequestProperty("Range","bytes="+done+"-");
      }
      readableByteChannel = Channels.newChannel(httpConn.getInputStream());
      fileOutputStream = itsThere ? new FileOutputStream(filePath) : new FileOutputStream(filePath,true);
      fileOutputChannel = fileOutputStream.getChannel();
      for (long position = done, size = httpConn.getContentLength(); position < size && !isCancelled(); ) {
        position += fileOutputChannel.transferFrom(readableByteChannel, position, 1 << 16);
      }
      //done
    }catch(Exception e){
      taskState = false;
      e.printStackTrace();

    }finally{
            //close streams conns etc
    }
    return taskState;
  }

}
```

This is the error stack trace that I get after 5 - 10 mins of download

```
/*
  javax.net.ssl.SSLException: Connection has been shutdown: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.checkEOF(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.AppInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read1(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.BufferedInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.MeteredStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at java.io.FilterInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at sun.net.www.protocol.http.HttpURLConnection$HttpInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at java.nio.channels.Channels$ReadableByteChannelImpl.read(Unknown Source)
  at com.objects.DownloadByteChannel.read(DownloadByteChannel.java:117)
  at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFromArbitraryChannel(Unknown Source)
  at sun.nio.ch.FileChannelImpl.transferFrom(Unknown Source)
  at com.core.DownloadTask.doInBackground(DownloadTask.java:154)
  at com.core.DownloadTask.doInBackground(DownloadTask.java:59)
  at com.util.ZSwingWorker$1.call(ZSwingWorker.java:286)
  at java.util.concurrent.FutureTask.run(Unknown Source)
  at com.util.ZSwingWorker.run(ZSwingWorker.java:325)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
  at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
  at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
Caused by: javax.net.ssl.SSLException: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at sun.security.ssl.Alerts.getSSLException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.fatal(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.handleException(Unknown Source)
  ... 18 more
Caused by: java.net.SocketException: Connection reset
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at java.net.SocketInputStream.read(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.readFully(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.InputRecord.read(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readRecord(Unknown Source)
  at sun.security.ssl.SSLSocketImpl.readDataRecord(Unknown Source)
  ... 18 more
*/
```

Usage:

```
public static void main(String[] args){
  int counter = 1;
  for(String url: urls){  
    new DownloadProcess(url,"\\\\fileshare.server\\xyz"+(counter++)+".txt").execute();
  }      
}
```

Comment: I can't see 'connection closed' snywhere, but I can see 'connection reset'.

Comment: Yes the Connection has been shutdown / Connection Reset. I will update the topic

Comment: **NO.** The connection has been neither closed nor shutdown. It has been reset. You **must** read and report errror messages accurately, and not guess at what they mean. 'Closed', 'shutdown', and 'reset' are three different actions, not three words for the same action.

Comment: Nothing could solve this. I caught that exception and added to the executorService back again as a new task. Keeps on looping but ends up downloading my files

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You are going to have to change your connection timeout serverside. I picked up a few links along the way if they are of any importance:

[Modify Session Security settings](https://help.salesforce.com/articleView?id=admin_sessions.htm&type=0)

[Lengthening salesforce session timeout](https://success.salesforce.com/answers?id=90630000000gpyQAAQ)

Hope this helps, good luck and let me know :)

Answer (score 0):

Connection Reset means the remote side is closing the connection with a TCP RST (reset) packet. You need to find out what the remote side isn't liking and fix it.

If the remote side is Apache maybe you are running into the KeepAliveTimeout value. By default that is 5 seconds. It really sounds like you are running into some sort of configured limit on the remote side. When that happens the server is kicking you off with a reset.

Comment: If you're talking about TCP keep-alive, the default is two hours. If you're talking about HTTP keep-alive, the timeout refers to the interval between sending the response and reading the next request on the same connection. Not to the length of time it takes to send a response.

Comment: @EJP i understand perfectly what Apache's KeepAliveTimeout means. I don't even know that Apache is the remote side. I mentioned it as the kind of server side thing the OP needs to look for. It really sounds like there is some configured limit on the server side being reached.

Comment: If it helps it is a Salesforce cloud

Comment: @Michael If you understand it perfectly, why did you adduce it as a possible cause when it isn't?